# HTTP debugging proxy for Linux and Mac

Tags: linux, http, macos, proxy, debugging

I use the [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) proxy to debug all kinds of HTTP issues on Windows. It's great for inspecting headers and responses across multiple pages.

Is there a good HTTP debugging proxy for Mac and Linux? I found [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/), but it's $50 once the trial runs out and it crashed on me. I could use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), but it's a pain.

Comment: See also: http://superuser.com/questions/42813/looking-for-http-debugging-proxy-for-mac-similar-to-fiddler-on-windows

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can of course, just use Fiddler on a Windows PC and point the Mac/Linux box at it.  http://www.fiddlerbook.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-NonWindows

You can also run Fiddler in a Windows or Linux virtual machine on the Mac itself: http://blogs.telerik.com/fiddler/posts/14-01-15/running-fiddler-in-virtualbox-on-mac

Comment: Thanks, Eric, for all the great work you've done with Fiddler. I'll be using that trick in future.

Comment: downvote, because i think the correct answer should be a proxy which run directly at linux. So i understand the question.

Comment: @FunThomas424242 You're confused. Fiddler does run directly on Linux.

Answer (score 26):

[Mitmproxy](http://mitmproxy.org/) is a useful command-line proxy tool.

It has also an user UI.

- From the command line run `mitmweb`
- Set up your app to use a proxy server and point it at http://127.0.0.1:8080
- Go to http://127.0.0.1:8081 to see all the requests in the "flow" tab. Very similar to the Google Chrome Console "Network" tab.

Answer (score 22):

[Zaproxy](https://www.zaproxy.org/), a fork of Paros, is a cross-platform open source debugging proxy and is actively maintained under OWASP.

Comment: Now located at GitHub: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ZAP

Answer (score 15):

Charles is $50 as you know, but I find it to be completely worth the money. A ton of features, including SSL support.

FWIW, I've never had it crash on me.

Comment: Charles Proxy is a really solid product. I use it, among other purposes, as an HTTP proxy on the my network. Then configure my mobile devices to use my IP address and designated port number as the proxy in the wifi settings.

Answer (score 6):

Wireshark won't help you if you have to debug HTTPS requests (unless you can get the encryption keys for both endpoints - see the Wireshark site for details). Firebug and Tamper Data are getting close, but for thorough analysis, I sometimes like to save a recorded session. I'd recommend giving [the OWASP Zed Attack Proxy](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project) (the successor of [Parosproxy](http://www.parosproxy.org/), which is no longer actively developed) a try. It is a Java application serving as a http(s) proxy; it provides quite a lot of features and proved to be very helpful to me in the past.

ZAP offers an easy autoconfiguration of Firefox. Bear in mind to do that on a separate (meaning: not for other browsing activities) Firefox profile: In order to intercept https, ZAP will install a new SSL certificate.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to try Live HTTP Headers add-on for Firefox.

Answer (score 4):

Paros works like a charm for me on my Ubuntu Jaunty x64. Just as simple as download, run, set proxy settings in browser to localhost:8080 and you are ready to inspect your http browsing.

It is Java so it works on Windows, Linux and Mac.

I prefer this to firefox plugin because I can use it with different browsers and software.

ParosProxy download:  http://sourceforge.net/projects/paros/

Paros hasn't been updated for many years. However there is an actively maintained fork of Paros - the OWASP Zed Attack Proxy (ZAP):  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of Chrome store apps now. I'm using [DHC by Restlet](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhc-resthttp-api-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm) now.

Answer (score 3):

I personally find Wireshark to be quite easy to use. Just apply a filter for HTTP traffic and right click on the traffic going/coming to/from your site and click "Follow TCP stream".

But, if you want something a little more specific for HTTP debugging I would recommend Firebug http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: Firebug is great and I use it often, but it only tracks HTTP requests for the current page. My question was brought about by debugging a problem with redirects.

Comment: Ahh that is true, sorry about that. But, yeah if you want to do that Fiddler would be your best bet for a user-friendly "HTTP debugger".

Answer (score 3):

If you limit yourself to Firefox, the [Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/966) extension is pretty solid.

Answer (score 3):

[Burp Proxy](https://portswigger.net/burp/proxy.html)

[Betwixt](https://github.com/kdzwinel/betwixt) - based on Chrome DevTools interface

Some additional options located on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175306/what-alternatives-are-there-to-fiddler-debugging-proxy).

Comment: wow Burp is a gem. And its free thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another option is something that doesn't require a desktop app. Runscope is a "cloud" based proxy that let's you debug requests. It can't capture requests on localhost or internal networks, but if you're debugging apps or third-party API integrations over the public internet, it can help.

(Disclaimer, I'm one of the founders.)

Answer (score 1):

If you can do some Perl, I think you should have a look at the HTTP::Proxy module.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [Proxy.app](http://www.websecurify.com/desktop/proxy.html) by Websecurify. It is 100% native, available from the Mac App Store.

Answer (score 1):

You can use chrome: `chrome://net-internals/#events`

Answer (score 1):

[ZAP 2.4.3 Standard](https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/Downloads) is the finest HTTP debugging proxy for Mac and Linux i can find. I have used Fiddler on windows but for Linux i faced similar problem and during my search i came to know about ZAP. I am using it and it has a very rich user interface.

Answer (score 0):

I know this an old question but I have ended up here many times looking for a solution for this.

I tried Wireshark ( Horrible )
Burp ( Ok just not good enough )
Fiddler mono version ( Buggy as hell )
Charles
& many more.

Non of these tools felt half as useful as fiddler on windows.

I found a new extension to Postman ( Nice tool for making http request ) Postman proxy it allows you to monitor http requests much the same way as fiddler does in windows.

Hope this helps someone.