# With multiple background images defined in a CSS class; Do browsers download them all?

Tags: css, performance

```
body {
   background: url(image.png);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(169,3,41,1) 0%, rgba(143,2,34,1) 44%, rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%);
}
```

I know the gradient will be shown and the .png overridden if I use Firefox. But will the browser still download the .png? What about other browsers, their vendor prefixes and behavior?

Comment: I can confirm Chrome does not download the image: http://fiddle.jshell.net/TGWhJ/1/show/.

Comment: I don't know of a definitive list, but take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104312/do-all-css-background-images-get-loaded-even-if-the-css-isnt-applied. Seems like you can just watch each browser's behavior with a debugging proxy to find out for sure.

Comment: you could start testing. chrome and opera have built in debuggers where you can check the resources downloaded. firefox has firebug and IE has "F12"

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on what browser you're using. For the most part, up to date browsers, such as chrome, don't download the files until they've read all the CSS statements I believe. Because you stated two background "images", it's not actually going to download the PNG because the statement is overwritten.

However, I would advise against this, because there are still a lot of users out there using old versions of browsers, and I can't guarantee how those browsers will act in this situation.

Comment: seems like IE7 for example downloads the PNG and ignores the vendor prefixed lines. So I don't see the problem doing this except for that some crappy browsers might download the PNG and then override it with the gradient. Which makes for extra load time.