# Http request tool that will show the actual request (trouble with the Firefox plugin Poster)

Tags: drupal, common-lisp, http-request, poster

I am trying to connect my common lisp application to a Drupal driven server site using http-post and I am having trouble debugging my request.  When I use the Firefox plugin Poster to make the request everything works fine but when I make the request from inside my common lisp application I get incorrect behavior.  I would really like to see the http-request produced by Poster but it seems to have no option for this, is there another little app that is similar but would show me the actual Request?  Or is there someway to get this out of Poster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you could use a debugging HTTP proxy. Some suggestions in [HTTP debugging proxy for Linux and Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617536/http-debugging-proxy-for-linux-and-mac).

You could also use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

As for the Common Lisp part, what library are you using? Are you logging in first? If using [Drakma](http://weitz.de/drakma/), are you using a cookie jar to pass the session cookies from one request to the other? (see the examples on the [documentation page](http://weitz.de/drakma/), search for `(make-instance 'cookie-jar)`)

Comment: Okay I'll check out the http debugging proxy.  i actually found something called HttpFox (another plugin for Firefox) that would show all the http requests made by Firefox.  As for the main problem I was having it was in fact Cookie related, I needed to pass back a session Cookie that was sent from the Drupal site.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Are you logged in to the Drupal site?
Then you might not have the correct session id in lisp.
You could try making the same request you did in Poster using curl from a command line.