# Login in a website with http post

Tags: java, android

i'm try to create an aplication to login in this website http://www.reclameaqui.com.br/ 
and when i put my login and password ,the aplication show me this :

03-01 22:34:47.220: W/SENCIDE(27717): 403 Forbidden

## Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /areadoconsumidor/on this server.

---

Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server atwww.reclameaqui.com.br Port 80
package com.sencide;

**This is the CODE**

```
    package com.sencide;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidLogin extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button ok,back,exit,site;
    TextView result;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

     // Login button clicked
        site = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        site.setOnClickListener(this);


        // Login button clicked
        ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        ok.setOnClickListener(this);

        result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lbl_result);

    }

    public void postLoginData() {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        /* logar no site */
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.reclameaqui.com.br/includes/autenticaUsuario.php");

        try {
            // Add user name and password
            EditText uname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
            String username = uname.getText().toString();

            EditText pword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_password);
            String password = pword.getText().toString();

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(6);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("identificador", username ));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("senha", password ));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("urlRedir", "http://www.reclameaqui.com.br/areadoconsumidor/"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tipo", "cadastro" ));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("x", "35" ));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("y", "24" ));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            Log.w("SENCIDE", "Execute HTTP Post Request");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            String str = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
            Log.w("SENCIDE", str);

            if(str.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
            {
                Log.w("SENCIDE", "TRUE");
                result.setText("Login successful");   
            }else
            {
                Log.w("SENCIDE", "FALSE");
                result.setText(str);                
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 

    private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        String line = "";
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        // Read response until the end
        try {
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) { 
                total.append(line); 
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Return full string
        return total;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view == ok){
            postLoginData();
        }
    }

}
```

what can i do to the app works great? someone help me;

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are posting to the wrong page.

`<form action="includes/autenticaUsuario.php" method="post" onsubmit="return valida_form(this)">`

the form appears to post to `http://www.reclameaqui.com.br/includes/autenticaUsuario.php`.

It also has hidden fields: `<input type="hidden" name="urlRedir" value="http://www.reclameaqui.com.br/areadoconsumidor/">`

and

`<input type="hidden" name="tipo" value="cadastro">`

Second, the username input is named `<input type="text" name="identificador">` and the password input is named `<input type="password" name="senha">` so I believe your BasicNamveValuePairs should be more like this: `new BasicNameValuePair("identificador", identificador)` and `new BasicNameValuePair("senha", senha)`

---

It should probably look something like this:

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tipo", "cadastro"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("urlRedir", "http://www.reclameaqui.com.br/areadoconsumidor/"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("identificador", identificador));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("senha", senha));
```

Comment: i follow your tips and i get the same error, i edit my post with the new code

Comment: @user2125667 It doesn't look like you added the hidden fields. You should add them as two more BasicNameValuePairs to the httppost.

Comment: Also, I had a typo in my message. The second BasicNamveValuePair for the password should be `new BasicNameValuePair("senha", senha)`

Comment: i edit again and i until get the same error, i've try with another site and i can get it work, but with this site apear that error.

Comment: At this point, you should do as jarmod said. If you have chrome, you can just use the Network tab in Developer Tools to view the request. See what is different, maybe it's a cookie or maybe they just filter useragents.

Answer (score 0):

Insert an intermediate HTTP proxy, or use some form of HTTP debugging so that you can compare the post url and all posted data from the working login versus your programmed login.  That will point out a number of problems.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617536/http-debugging-proxy-for-linux-and-mac or other web pages on how to set up a proxy.  Then configure the proxy to point at the target web-site, and change your webapp to point at the proxy.  Alternatively, just use tcpdump/wireshark to capture/present the HTTP traffic.

Comment: i use a http traffic and i get it work with another site, but with reclameaqui. doesn't works

Comment: There must be some difference between the working HTTP login, and your failing login.  Compare what is sent in the two cases.  What is different?